# Writing CSV file with complex list data

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a complex list of dictionaries to CSV, but getting encoding and value errors. I haven't really worked with data in Python, so I'm new to this.

```python
import csv

with open("output.csv", 'rb', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in row_num:  
        writer.writerows(row_num)

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
 ValueError: binary mode doesn't take a newline argument
```

If I remove the encoding, I get: `io.UnsupportedOperation: write`.

Here is a sample of the data that I want to write to a CSV file with header being the key like `code` and  `hid`:

```python
 [OrderedDict([('code', '7nsdjfk'), ('hid', '220'), ('name', 'sdjlnj dkldk slkdlkd'), ('code2', '99'), ('description', 'dmldc skdlmls wsldfml'), ('average', '0'), ('ccr', '0.218'), ('ccr_price', '399'), ('dusk sdks', '603'), ('dcfl lldcml', '3847.9'), ('id', 'sdklcldkcdslkcmsdl202i')]), OrderedDict([ ...]), OrderedDict([...])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'rb'` stands for 'read as binary'. So, it reads the data from the file considering equivalent of binary.

It does not take any extra arguments, as per doc.
Simply use:

```
with open("output.csv", 'w') as f:
```

You can try to use `'w'` in place of `'rb'` mode just to **write the file**.

Words from the documentation....

> Files opened in binary mode (including 'b' in the mode argument)
>   return contents as bytes objects without any decoding.

Modes:

```
'r' - open for reading (default)
'w' - open for writing, truncating the file first
'x' - open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists
'a' - open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
'b' - binary mode
't' - text mode (default)
'+' - open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Changing the mode to text-plain

CSV stands for comma-separated value. This format consists on plain text.

Moreover, `'rb'` means *read* `r` *file as a binary* `b`, which is incongruent with plain-text.

Try with `'wt'` or just `'w'` to actually **write** a plain-text file.

[Check the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to learn more about the `open()` function.

#### Edit: Write data into file

I have come up with this solution:

- `csv.writer` is replaced by `csv.DictWriter`, which intakes the `keys`
- `writer.writeheader()` inserts the `keys` as headers separated by commas
- `writer.writerows(row_num)` writes the values into the file, one line per `OrderedDict`

```python
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

row_num = [OrderedDict([('code', '7nsdjfk'), ('hid', '220'), ('name', 'sdjlnj dkldk slkdlkd'), ('code2', '99'), ('description', 'dmldc skdlmls wsldfml'),
                        ('average', '0'), ('ccr', '0.218'), ('ccr_price', '399'), ('dusk sdks', '603'), ('dcfl lldcml', '3847.9'), ('id', 'sdklcldkcdslkcmsdl202i')]),
           OrderedDict([('code', 'a'), ('hid', '1'), ('name', 'b'), ('code2', '1'), ('description', 'c'),
                        ('average', '1'), ('ccr', '0.123'), ('ccr_price', '133'), ('dusk sdks', '133'), ('dcfl lldcml', '1345.9'), ('id', 'abcde')]),
        ]

keys = row_num[0].keys()

with open("output.csv", 'wt', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
    writer.writeheader()

    # write values
    writer.writerows(row_num)
```

The results in `output.csv` are:

```
code,hid,name,code2,description,average,ccr,ccr_price,dusk sdks,dcfl lldcml,id
7nsdjfk,220,sdjlnj dkldk slkdlkd,99,dmldc skdlmls wsldfml,0,0.218,399,603,3847.9,sdklcldkcdslkcmsdl202i
a,1,b,1,c,1,0.123,133,133,1345.9,abcde
```

Comment: Thanks! It's still not reading in properly. I'm only getting the "keys" if I use list csv reader. If I use the dictionary CSV reader, I get the following error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'"

Comment: @NateP I have extended my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: @NateP Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.